# How to initialize an `Eigen::VectorXd` using values from another `Eigen::VectorXd` vector, based on a `vector<int>` of indexes

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, eigen

I'm interested in initializing an `Eigen::VectorXd` vector using values from another `Eigen::VectorXd` vector, based on a `vector<int>` of indexes that will point out which exactly elements will be used.

That is,

```
// This is the large vector from which I'll take the values to 
// initialize the second, shorter one
int N = 100;
Eigen::VectorXd V(N);
V.setRandom(N);

// This is the vector of indexes that'll be used to specify 
// which elements of V will be used in the initialization of x
vector<int> ids = {1, 3, 0, 20};

// This is the vector I want to initialize
Eigen::VectorXd x(ids.size());
```

Now, what I want `x` to be is the following:

x(0) = V(1)

x(1) = V(3)

x(2) = V(0)

x(4) = V(20)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the devel branch (will become 3.4) you can do:

```
x = V(ids);
```

With Eigen 3.3, you have to write your own for loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)
Btw, do you have any insight on when this will be available?

Comment: let's hope for end of spring

Comment: Nice! Thanks for your answers :)